# c# convert string to python object

Tags: c#, data-structures, casting, ironpython

There is all kinds of craziness happening in my shop. The request is an odd one, but understand I have no choice. I need to convert the string representation of an ironpython dictionary into an actual ironpython dictionary... and I need to do it in c#. The dictionary is being retrieved from a database, so there is no chance I can get it in any other form.

I have made some progress here. So far I have the following:

```
        string python_dict = SqlSession.getPythonDictFromDatabase();

        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();

        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(python_dict, SourceCodeKind.Expression);

        PythonDictionary dict = source.Execute<PythonDictionary>();
```

The above code successfully converts the string into a python dictionary. Great so far. Unfortunately, the nested classes within the dictionary are still strings. There are all sorts of things in there varying from strings and ints to SetCollections. I need the entire datastructure converted into the c# representation of python objects. I could conceivably iterate through the structure whilst performing conversions just like I did with the dict initially. This seems very messy. It also seems fragile.

The worst part about all this? I actually had this working about a month ago. The source code was lost. Anyone know how I can convert this string into a fully represented python data structure?

Comment: Can you simply use JSON - encode in C#, decode in Python or vice-versa - and just pass it as a text? I mean, sure, it's a "punt", but it might Just Work .. Anyway, all serializers/deserializers (including those that use JSON) just "iterate through the structure while performing conversions", it's just a matter of supporting all the conversions that need to be supported for the given data/domain. As for "[not] losing" code, consider a SCM tool like Git or Hg ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you really *have* to do it this way (and I'm not sure why...), and you can't just use the C# Dictionary data struct then:

> I could conceivably iterate through the structure whilst performing
>   conversions just like I did with the dict initially.

This is exactly what I'd do.  Create an function for parsing the string and convert each data struct into the C# equivalent (psuedo code ahoy)

```
PythonDictionary convert_to_python_dict_from_string(dict_string)
{    
    // check type of each field
    // perform appropriate conversions
    // add to python dict object
    // return object 
}
```

The function to do the conversion will be as fragile / iron clad as you make it really, just like any other serializer

Good luck! :)